# Newrelic doesn't show request attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

I've added the newrelic gem to my production Rails app and can see web transactions in the newrelic site. However, the HTTP transactions do not include the HTTP payload such as request parameters and HTTP headers.
Here's [my newreclic configuration file](https://gist.github.com/tal-moshayov/589803f80d2f1b6c765e)

Here's a screen capture from the newrelic site:

Given the attached configuration file where `capture_params` is true, I expected to see parameters logged.

[image: new relic yml]

**Any advice to troubleshoot this would be highly appreciated.**

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to comment but I don't have enough rep to do it.

Where do you want to see those params? Whatever I want to see them in the errors panel I'd usually add them as custom parameters.

Unfortunately if you go past 255 characters they won't show at all, neither warn you about it. Unfortunately this was undocumented, I had a ticket opened for getting that question answered. Notice that you also have a limit on the custom parameter count as well, can't remember which value it was.

I usually do something like this:

```
if (str.length() < NEW_RELIC_CUSTOM_PARAMETERS_MAX_CHARS) {
            NewRelic.addCustomParameter(customParameter, str);
} else {
            NewRelic.addCustomParameter(customParameter, str.substring(0, NEW_RELIC_CUSTOM_PARAMETERS_MAX_CHARS - 3)
                + "...");
}
```